# Android Adding Inset Border To ListViews

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a listview  and wondering how to add border to my list items like the below image

[image]

divider drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#cdcdcd"/>    
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

List view.xml

```
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a divider in your listview.

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_line"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
```

or add a line at the bottom in your custom layout , make sure that there should be no padding or margins at the bottom when defining a custom layout for listview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

     >


                ................      add views of your choice   

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/divider_line" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: adding divider will give a solid line what i need is the same effect , it seems to be an inset border

Comment: i have edited the question now it shows the code for my divider drawable and using that i get a simple solid border

Comment: I edit the answer see it again. Use a custom layout and add the view at bottom . For inset border take the 9-patch image designed or create a custom drawable . Follow this for custom drawables . http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Surely it does . Please do not forget to accept this answer as an appreciation once the problem is fuxed. Thanks

Comment: i already voted it up as it helped me, but again i cannot take it as a complete answer ( hope you understand )

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
        android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
```

In your listView xml attributes

Comment: that's the thing i am not able to achieve this effect using xml drawable

Answer (score 0):

please enter this code on oncreate() method

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listchilds);

    int[] colors = { 0xFFDAD7CE, 0xFFF9F8F5, 0 }; 
    listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors));
    listView.setDividerHeight(2);
```